# match values from data.frames with different number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data.frames `df1` and `df2`, `df1` has 12,869 rows and `df2` has 173398. `df1` has 2 columns the first one is numeric and the second one is a character. `df2` has also 2 columns both numeric. I want to replace the numbers in `df2` based on the character values of `df1[,2]`. Here is how the head of my data.frames looks like:

```
>head(df1)
 ids  genes
1  1   NSD1
2  2  MAST2
3  3    PHB
4  4 IKBKAP
5  5  CDC42
6  6   SAT1

>head(df2)
    X1   X2
1  933 3982
2 1791 2504
3 3379 3394
4 1381 9732
5 2002 6408
6 3947 7579
```

Many thanks

I've tried these two approaches:

```
df2[,1] <- setNames(df1$genes, df2$X1)[as.character(unlist(df2[,1]))]

df2[,1] <- df2[match(df1[,1], df2[,1]),2]
```

But they don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a different `df2` for demonstration, you might do:

```
df2 <- read.table(text="
X1   X2
1  2 3
2 1 4
3 5 1
4 3 5
5 1 2
6 2 1", header=T)

df2$X1 <- as.character(df1$genes)[match(df2$X1, df1$ids)]
df2$X2 <- as.character(df1$genes)[match(df2$X2, df1$ids)]

df2
     X1     X2
1 MAST2    PHB
2  NSD1 IKBKAP
3 CDC42   NSD1
4   PHB  CDC42
5  NSD1  MAST2
6 MAST2   NSD1
```

HTH